# File last update

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm developing a web application with angular and node.js.
I have a Database which has to be updated everytime a certain file is modified.

To know if this file have been modified I want to look at the last update date but I've not find how to do it with javascript.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified

Comment: Where does your file reside? Client side or Server side?

Comment: My file is located on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has `File` api which provides api for accessing files. `lastModified` propertly will give file modified timestamp. Documentation is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified

Comment: When I used this, I have to upload myself the file to check. How can I make it automatic ? I've seen that it was not possible with javascript.

Comment: Since javascript api's can't access your file system directly via browser, Automation is not possible in straight forward way. But in nodeJS you can automate file processing since it can access system's file system